# Lambert-Function Solution of $\ln(x) = x-2$

Tags: functions, lambert-w

Found an equation on AP Calculus:$$ \ln(x) = x-2.$$ Two solutions:  0.15859, 3.14619.
Got the first solution thus:

$e^{\ln(x)}     = e^{x-2}$

$x           = e^x e^{-2}$

$x (e^{-x})    = e^{-2}$

$-x (e^{-x})   = - e^{-2}$

$W[-x (e^{-x})]= W[- e^{-2}]$

$-x          = W[- e^{-2}]$ .

Then I used `productlog [- e^-2]` on WolframAlpha.com to get 0.15859.
Does anyone know how to get the other root, 3.14619?

(The people who originally solved this equation used a graphing calculator. Would rather do it the long way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second branch of the Lambert's function.

You can also notice that $|(\ln x)'|<1$ around that solution, so that the fixed-point iterations

$$x_{n+1}=\ln(x_n)+2$$ will converge.

Of course, Newton's iterations are much faster,

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\ln x_n-x_n+2}{\dfrac{1}{x_n}-1}.$$

Comment: There seem to be different opinions concerning the numbering of branches. Wolfram Alpha wants the input productlog [-1,- e^-2], in this case. Answer: $-3.14619322062058258523706102852136825288866204618248842603\ldots$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: read "the *other* branch".

Comment: You mean *another* branch, I guess, as there are infinitely many. The other values (e.g. branch +1)are complex, though.