# Solving $a x = [\ln(x) - b]^c$

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I'm trying to solve the nonlinear equation $a x = [\ln(x) - b]^c$ for x, where a, b, and c are constants, for a project.  I've tried numerical techniques like in Excel Solver, but the solutions seem to be at local points where the solvers get stuck.  Those "solutions" aren't sufficiently accurate for my purpose.  I'm thinking that there may be a closed-form solution, perhaps using the Lambert W function after converting the equation to the proper form if possible.  I'm not a mathematician, so any help finding the global root(s) is much appreciated.

Comment: "Numerical techniques"???  How could numerical techniques *ever* solve a symbolic equation?

Comment: Values are obviously assigned to the constants.

Comment: If that is so, then please specify the constants.  (Ummm... why didn't you????)

Comment: As stated, I was looking for a closed-form solution.

Comment: Then your efforts at numerical techniques were for nought, even before you tried them.

Comment: I tried numerical techniques on the equation having my constant values and then sought a closed-form solution.  The other two individuals were incredibly helpful (and unpretentious) and have answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that we want to get the equation to be of the form $y(x)e^{y(x)}$ so we can use the [Lambert-$W$ function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) that inverts this: $W\left(y(x)e^{y(x)}\right)=y(x)$:
$$ax=\left(\ln x-b\right)^c\\
a^{1/c}x^{1/c}=\ln x-b\\
e^{a^{1/c}x^{1/c}}=xe^{-b}\\
e^{(-1/c) a^{1/c}x^{1/c}}=x^{-1/c}e^{b/c}\\
x^{1/c}e^{(-1/c) a^{1/c}x^{1/c}}=e^{b/c}\\
-1/c\cdot a^{1/c}x^{1/c}e^{(-1/c) a^{1/c}x^{1/c}}=-1/c\cdot a^{1/c}e^{b/c}$$
Now, we can use $W$:
$$-1/c\cdot a^{1/c}x^{1/c}=W\left(-1/c\cdot a^{1/c}e^{b/c}\right)\\
x=\frac{(-c)^c}{a}W^c\left(-1/c\cdot a^{1/c}e^{b/c}\right)
$$
You can use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to compute $W$ but write "product log of" instead of "Lambert-$W$ of."

Comment: This answer is equivalent to the first answer by @Chinny84 (aside from a/b instead of a) and is cleaner.  Thanks to you too!

Comment: @user20730 No problem!

Comment: Only certain real numbers for c > 0 seem to be valid for evaluating (-c)^c.  Do you or anyone else know why?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user20730 That's because if $c$ is of the form $2^{-n}$, $(-c)^c$ is like taking the $n$-th square root of a negative number which produces multiples of the imaginary unit, $i$ where $i^2=-1$. For example, let $c=2^{-1}$, we get $$(-c)^c=\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt\frac12=\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}$$ If $c$ is of the form $d2^{-n}+e$ for $d\neq 2^n$ and $e\neq f-d2^{-n}$ for some $f$ not of the form of $c$ I am talking about, the same happens but you get so-called complex numbers of the form $a+bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are not imaginary or what's called real.

Comment: @user20730 Look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number for imaginary numbers and at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number for complex ones. And I advice you look at youtube videos or even read a book about complex numbers because they are very interesting, for example, the formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ involves exponentials, sine and cosine and real and imaginary numbers it also leads to $e^{i\pi}=-1$ for $x=\pi$.

Comment: Your example with c = 1/2 helped me understand.  0 < c < 1 for my problem, so I guess that there are very few solutions that are real numbers.

Comment: Could there be another closed-form solution, which doesn't involve (-c)^c?

Comment: @user20730 I don't think there exist such a closed form. It just happens that you get complex values for the $c$'s I talked about. It might be helpful to give a bit of context to your problem, maybe I can help you dodge the problem.

Comment: I greatly appreciate that but am fairly certain then that there's no way around it.  It turns out that a numerical method appears to get me close enough after all, so I should be all be set.  I learned quite a bit in the process.  You and @Chinny84 are brilliant.

Comment: @user20730 Thank you for the kind words, hope your project goes well.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/c}x^{1/c} = \ln x - b
$$
let $x^{1/c} = y$ we have
$$
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/c} y = \ln y^c - b = c\ln y - b
$$
we then have
$$
\frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/c} y  = z
$$
we have
$$
z = \ln \left[\frac{c}{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/c}}z\right] - \frac{b}{c}
$$
or
$$
z = \ln (\lambda z) - \frac{b}{c} = \ln z + \ln \lambda - \frac{b}{c} = \ln z + \lambda_1
$$
which is
$$
\mathrm{e}^{z} = \mathrm{e}^{\lambda_1}z  = \lambda_2 z
$$
which is
$$
-z\mathrm{e}^{-z} = -\frac{1}{\lambda_2}
$$
which is
$$
-z = \mathrm{W}\left[-\frac{1}{\lambda_2}\right]
$$
or
$$
z = -\mathrm{W}\left[-\frac{1}{\lambda_2}\right]
$$
where $\mathrm{W}$ is the lambert function.

$$
\frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/c} x^{1/c}  =  -\mathrm{W}\left[-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{b}{c} - \ln \left(\frac{c}{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/c}}\right)}\right]
$$

you can compare with this [post on lambert solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643193/lambert-function-solution-of-lnx-x-2) which solves $\ln x = x- 2$ which is equivalent to a few steps above.

Comment: was so helpful and quick that he posted his answer while I was editing my question to remove the accidental "b" before the expression on the right-hand side!  The answer is correct if (a/b) is replaced by just "a."